# Cookie set not working with django and next js app hosted on azure and confiured to use custom domain

Tags: django, azure, next.js, cookies

I have two applications. A next.js frontend app and a Django backend app. The backend uses Django's session storage and I'm trying to set cookies in the browser. This was working on localhost. I'm using Azure to host my application. I bought my own domain called something.xyz. I put my frontend as an A record with host as @ in my DNS configuration and my backend as a CNAME with host as ser. There are also TXT records for azure config. When I go to ser.something.xyz I can access my backend. I can also access my frontend when I go to something.xyz.

I have set both `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE` to `None`. I have set both `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to either `something.xyz`, `.something.xyz`, or `ser.something.xyz`. I also tried putting `https://` in front (that's probably wrong but I'm desperate)

I know this question has been asked before, but I just can't seem to get it to work. I have changed my settings several times

This is the message I'm getting from the network tab: `csrftoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Domain=['something.xyz']; expires=Mon, 03 Feb 2025 22:41:48 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure`
`this attempt to set a cookie via a Set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url`
I getting this message for both my csrf cookie and sessionid cookie

Am I missing something? Should I just use tokens?

Also, I swear at one point the csrf cookie was setting but I changed the settings and now both won't set. I can't remember what I changed.

Comment: okay well turns out I put my `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE ` in a list which is why there are brackets around ['something.xyz']. Just had to change that in my settings.py

Comment: please share the your  answer/post your answer